# Debian Camera isn't working

Tags: camera, debian, virtualbox

I have never before worked in Debian environment. I have some problem with camera, I was looking for answers but find nothing.

I am working in virtualbox, the camera is plugged through virtualbox. I am using is my laptop webcam, Lenovo EasyCamera. When I lauch program, for example cheese, I get this message :

```
jakub@debian:~$ cheese
OpenGL Warning: crPixelCopy3D:  simply crMemcpy'ing from srcPtr to dstPtr

(cheese:3368): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel


libv4l2: error turning on stream: Brak miejsca na urządzeniu

** (cheese:3368): WARNING **: Error starting streaming on device '/dev/video0'.


** (cheese:3368): WARNING **: Could not negotiate format
```

When cheese is working, the diode from the cam is on, so camera is working, but why Debian cannot show me the image.

I hope you will know what to do. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the same as this issue:

[libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394712/libv4l2-error-turning-on-stream-no-space-left-on-device)

You probably need to enable USB 2.0 in your virtual machine and pass the device into your guest OS using a high-speed USB host controller (EHCI).

You may need the VirtualBox Extension Pack, I remember it being required for USB 2.0 in the past. I can't find any current information about that, though, perhaps EHCI support is now included already.